# ajax response display zero

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

I'm using ajax in WordPress. the problem is while getting the response from ajax it shows "0"

[image: my ajax response message]

```
function verifymsg()
{
var verifymobile = $('#verifymobile').val();
var otpmobile = $('#mobile').val(); 
alert(verifymobile);
alert(otpmobile);
   var data = {
        'action': 'verifyotp_ajax',
        'verifymobile': verifymobile,'otpmobile': otpmobile
    };
    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        alert(response);
        $('#send').css("display", "none");
        $('#verify').css("display", "block");
    });
```

return false;
}

This is the WordPress code

```
add_action('wp_ajax_sendotp_ajax', 'sendotp_ajax_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_sendotp_ajax', 'sendotp_ajax_callback');
function sendotp_ajax_callback() {   
$verifymobile=$_POST['verifymobile'];
$otpmobile=$_POST['otpmobile']
if($otpmobile=="success")
{
    echo "success";
}}}
```

Comment: In which file above code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of echo response use `exit;` or `wp_die();` code , it will remove zero.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_sendotp_ajax', 'sendotp_ajax_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_sendotp_ajax', 'sendotp_ajax_callback');
function sendotp_ajax_callback() {   
$verifymobile=$_POST['verifymobile'];
$otpmobile=$_POST['otpmobile']
if($otpmobile=="success")
{
    echo "success";exit;
}}}
```

For more help : [Click here](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) and see under heading **Error Return Values** .

Answer (score 0):

You can use `die()` or `exit()` or `wp_die()` to stop execution of page after your condition getting true, so when if condition runs then it will only return 'success' and it will stop page execution.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_sendotp_ajax', 'sendotp_ajax_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_sendotp_ajax', 'sendotp_ajax_callback');
function sendotp_ajax_callback() {   
$verifymobile=$_POST['verifymobile'];
$otpmobile=$_POST['otpmobile']
if($otpmobile=="success")
{
    echo "success";exit;
}}}
```